# QListWidget align items

Tags: qt

I create QListWidget with some items.

```
QHBoxLayout* h_layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    h_layout->setMargin( 0 );
    menu_list_widget_  = new QListWidget;
    menu_list_widget_->setFlow(QListView::TopToBottom);
    menu_list_widget_->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
    menu_list_widget_->setMovement(QListView::Static);
    menu_list_widget_->setFixedWidth( 100 );

    QListWidgetItem* lwi;
    menu_list_widget_->addItem( lwi = new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(":/icons/color_pencils.png"), "Цвета") );
    lwi->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    menu_list_widget_->addItem( lwi = new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(":/icons/font.png"), "Шрифт") );
    lwi->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    lwi->setHidden( true );
// etc
    h_layout->addWidget(menu_list_widget_, 0, Qt::AlignHCenter)
```

But items don't have center align

[image]

Why?

Comment: You have set text alignment to 'center' and the text is aligned correctly within each item. The problem is - the items are not aligned within list widget. And I'm afraid, this is how icon mode works. `setUniformItemSizes(true)` helps a bit, but does not solve the problem. You can also try to set list's minimum and maximum width to the width of the longest text of your items and forbid word wraping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some modification of your code, but the main is adding [`QListWidgetItem::setSizeHint()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#setSizeHint) for each element:

```
QListWidgetItem* lwi = new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(":Image/pinwheel.png"), "Цвета");
lwi->setSizeHint(QSize(256, 52));
listWidget->addItem( lwi );
lwi->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

lwi =  new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(":Image/pinwheel.png"), "Управление и что-то еще");
lwi->setSizeHint(QSize(256, 52));
listWidget->addItem( lwi );
lwi->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```

Now it looks aligned for me:

[image]

Comment: It took me some time to find why this should be centered. The trick you did is to set the sizeHint width of the icon equal to the widget width. Effectively, the icons look centered, but in truth the items are still left-aligned.